# Change the sequence of background images

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript function to display a sequence of background images.
What I want is to change to sequence for every page with php. In this case I want to substitute the x in bg_x_ps.jpg with a number in the range of 1 to 8.
Each background must have an unique number.

```
$.vegas( 'slideshow', {
    delay: 34000,
    backgrounds: [
        { src: "http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_2_ps.jpg", fade: 4000 },
        { src: 'http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_4_ps.jpg', fade: 4000 },
        { src: 'http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_5_ps.jpg', fade: 4000 },
        { src: 'http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_7_ps.jpg', fade: 4000 }
    ]
} )( 'overlay' );
```

Comment: Why do you want to use PHP in substituting the numbers and not just use Javascript itself ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

...

var indices = [], x;
while(indices.length < 4) {
    x = parseInt(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8), 10);
    x = (x == 0) ? 1 : x;
    if(indices.indexOf(x) == -1) indices.push(x);
}

$.vegas( 'slideshow', {
    delay: 34000,
    backgrounds: [
        { src: "http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_"+indices[0]+"_ps.jpg", fade: 4000 },
        { src: "http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_"+indices[1]+"_ps.jpg", fade: 4000 },
        { src: "http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_"+indices[2]+"_ps.jpg", fade: 4000 },
        { src: "http://sionvalais.com/images/bg_"+indices[3]+"_ps.jpg", fade: 4000 }
    ]
} )( 'overlay' );

...

});
```

Comment: If I would like to show 4 sequences (images) out of 12 images. Do I need to change the 8 to 12?

Comment: Yes, you can change 8 to match the total number of images you have in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Just build your order of images within an PHP array. Then parse it to json (maybe with `json_encode()`) and send it to your javascript.